# TDE and Replication, Log Shipping and Mirorring

Tags: sql-server, encryption

Does Replication/Log Shipping/Mirroring interferes with Transparent Data Encryption (TDE)?

I expect so see no impact on those processes if DTE is activated... Please let me know if you have other experiences...

Answer (score 1):

For replication, there should be nothing to do as its a disconnected copy of your data. Just make sure that you aren't replicating any of the sensitive data that caused you to encrypt the primary in the first place!

For mirroring and log shipping, I think you need to have the certificate that protects the database master key restored at the secondary side in order to bring the database online. If it were me, I'd restore that certificate now so that you're not scrambling to do it in the case of a failover.